# R ggplot compare similar (but not identical) columns of categorical data

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data

I've got a dataset which looks like this:

| platform | twitter_context | facebook_context | insta_context |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Twitter | Hashtag | NA | NA |
| Facebook | NA | Facebook Group | NA |
| Instagram | NA | NA | Public Figure |
| Instagram | NA | NA | Hashtag |
| Facebook | NA | A friend | NA |
| Twitter | Someone I follow | NA | NA |

…
total of rows > 1600

What I would like to achieve is a bar chart which compares the frequency of the categories in those "_context" columns by "platfom".

I have used ggplot before to draw a bar chart that combines two variables.
But here, the categories in those "_contexts" are similar, but not identical.

As each context column only applies to one platform, I tried to merge the three context columns in a new column using the mutate function. However, I failed to make it work properly: When I ran three mutate lines consecutively the NAs would always overwrite previous categories.
I tried to solve this with if/else_if-conditions, to have only proper data pasted to the new column (and ignore those NAs). But this idea was doomed by my lack of syntactical understanding.

I suppose there must be a way to get this right, however, I couldn't do it. (Did I mention I am quite new to this?)

My intention was that I could then plot a chart using the new "all_contexts" column and split it up on the x axis by platform.
(The labelling would still be a mess, but possibly that could be fixed by applying levels.)

A different approach I could imagine would be to have ggplot draw three independent bar charts which then would have to be manually standardized, unless there are ways to "concatenate" such somehow in a single plot.

Very likely this rookie problem has already been covered in a thread which I was unable to find.
Can someone point me into the right direction? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of ways to transform your data to prepare it for the plot that you want to create. One way is illustrated here, where we use `pivot_longer()` and remove rows that are NA, and then count the number of rows by `platform` and `context`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ggdata <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with('context'), names_to = "p", values_to = "context") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(context)) %>% 
  count(platform,context)
```

Now, you can directly pass the frame as is to `ggplot()` using `geom_col()`, or you could add rows for the platform/context combinations that are not represented.

Here is an example of the former approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ggdata, aes(platform, n, fill=context)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
The pivot_longer () function was really what I needed. I could effectively draw the chart I need.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved! Here's the resulting chart:
[image: Intraplatform Kontext / Platform]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).